Docker-compose up returns Error:invalid reference format
I'm testing docker-compose and docker-compose.yaml worked well on local.
And then I just copied this file and pasted on my AWS instance.
But on AWS instance "docker-compose up" command returns "ERROR: invalid reference format"
docker-compose.yaml
docker-compose.yaml
version: '3'
services:
  web:
    build: .
    container_name: django
    command: python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000
    volumes:
      - ./project_django:/app
    ports:
      - "8000:8000"
    depends_on:
      - mysql
      - mongodb
      - redis

  mysql:
    image: mysql:5.7
    container_name: mysql
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: example
      MYSQL_DATABASE: mydatabase
      MYSQL_USER: myuser
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: mypassword
    ports:
      - "3306:3306"
    volumes:
      - ./mysql_data:/var/lib/mysql

  mongodb:
    image: mongo
    container_name: mongodb
    ports:
      - "27017:27017"
    volumes:
      - ./mongodb_data:/data/db

  redis:
    image: redis
    container_name: redis
    ports:
      - "6379:6379"
    volumes:
      - ./redis_data:/data


dockerfile
FROM python:3.11.4

WORKDIR /app

COPY ./project_django/ /app
RUN pip install --upgrade pip
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt

CMD ["python manage.py runserver"]



What is the complete actual error message?  Are you just copying the Compose file, or your entire application tree?  As you've written the Compose it can't run without the entire local tree present.  I might try to restructure this so that your application references an image: in ECR (or another repository) and doesn't override the Dockerfile with volumes: or command:.  The image's CMD is wrong (it needs to be three separate words, and it probably needs to include 0.0.0.0:8000 as a fourth word) but it also isn't being used because of the Compose override.
